# Bulk assigning new SMTP addresses & new company name with powershell based on csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, azure-active-directory, office365, endpoint

I have to create a Powershell script that assigns a new main SMTP address to users of a csv file. They also need some other addresses. Besides that, those users need to change their company name. I am really new to all that stuff and tried to cobble some stuff together which wouldn´t work and it´s driving me crazy. :(

If you need more info please tell me. :)

Here is the code I´ve tried so far:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
Connect-AzureAD -Confirm

#Assigning addresses & company
Import-CSV "C:\CSVPowershell\userstest.csv" | ForEach {
Set-Mailbox $_.Identity -EmailAddresses @{add= $_.MainEmailAddress}
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.Identity -CompanyName $_.Company
}


#close
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Please check the below workaround:

#### CSV file

```
UserName, Mailform1, Mailform2 
aaa test, atest@companyname.com , atest@companyname_Dept.com
bbb test, btest@companyname.com , btest@companyname_Dept.com
ccc test, ctest@companyname.com , ctest@companyname_Dept.com
```

#### PowerShell Script

> Note: In your code, you are missing the operation **add**. Either you have to use **Add / Remove** in your script to perform the related operation.

```
    Import-CSV "C:\Users\Admin\UserEmailAddress.csv" | ForEach 
    {
        # Changing the Main Email address into your required Email.
        #Adding Multiple Email addresses (here 2 Email addresses)
        Set-Mailbox $_.UserName -EmailAddresses @{add= $_.Mailform1, $_.Mailform2}
    }
```

Suppose you are trying to add only **one SMTP address** to User follow the below:

##### CSV File

```
UserName, Mailform1
aaa test, atest@companyname.com 
bbb test, btest@companyname.com 
ccc test, ctest@companyname.com
```

##### PowerShell Script

```
    Import-CSV "C:\Users\Admin\UserEmailAddress.csv" | ForEach 
    {
        # Changing the Main Email address into your required Email.
        
        Set-Mailbox $_.UserName -EmailAddresses @{add= $_.Mailform1}
    }
```

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-user-mailboxes/add-or-remove-email-addresses) for more information

Comment: HI and sorry for my late answer! I´ve adjusted the script in the description based on your recommendation. But I am receiving the following error code: 

A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'EmailAddresses'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Set-Mailbox
    + PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com

I don´t know why it´s not recognizing "EmailAddresses" as it says to use it in the MS documentation you linked. 
Can you please assist? Thanks so much!